# org.sikuli.script.SikuliXception: loadlib: opencv_java342.dll not in any libs folder

Tags: selenium, sikuli-x

SikuliX Version: 2.0.4

Note: 2.0.5 is having clash with selenium version 4.0.0. Hence using this version. I did take the image after testing from sikuliX IDE only.

Getting the **SikuliXception** while trying to click an object in webpage.

**Method:-**

```
 public void click(String imagePath) throws FindFailed {
        Screen screen = new Screen();
        Pattern pp = new Pattern(imagePath);
        screen.click(pp);
    }
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>boo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>foo</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.version>2.6.0</serenity.version>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.11.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-alpha10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.sukgu</groupId>
        <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
           
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>2</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>foo/boo</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Error:-**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.sikuli.script.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:127)
        
        Caused by: org.sikuli.script.SikuliXception: loadlib: opencv_java342.dll not in any libs folder
        at org.sikuli.script.support.RunTime.libsLoad(RunTime.java:1467)
        at org.sikuli.script.support.RunTime.loadLibrary(RunTime.java:1658)
        at org.sikuli.script.Finder$Finder2.<clinit>(Finder.java:515)
        at org.sikuli.script.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:127)
        at Types.UserInterface.Utilities.Sikuli.click(Sikuli.java:25)
        at BusinessComponents.ClinicalPortal.Devices.Fleet.UserInterface.Pages.Parent.UI_Fleet.clickLinkOrUnlinkIcon(UI_Fleet.java:33)
        at BusinessComponents.ClinicalPortal.Devices.Fleet.UserInterface.Pages.StepDefinitionFiles.UI_Fleet_SDF.linkOrUnlink(UI_Fleet_SDF.java:14)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66)
        at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:24)
        at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
        at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:92)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:64)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:104)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:73)
        at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:151)
        at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:135)
        at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberSerenityRunner.runChild(CucumberSerenityRunner.java:259)
        at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberSerenityRunner.runChild(CucumberSerenityRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberSerenityRunner$RunCucumber.evaluate(CucumberSerenityRunner.java:287)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:377)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:248)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:456)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:595)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)
```

Has anyone faced this error before? If yes, please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\usernamehere\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixLibs\ and you will find opencv dll and just rename it as per error message you are getting that will fix this issue